# Release version not working properly in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, apk

I could run the app on emulators without any problems. But when I install on real device using apk file some of the pages in the app are working fine.. But some pages dont.. May I know if there is any fix for this. I have given my code below..

Thanks in advance

```
     searchFlag
            ? SearchResultsListView(searchText)
            : Expanded(
                child: FutureBuilder(
                  future: getParentCategoryList(context),
                  builder: (context, data) {
                    if (data.hasData) {
                      return CategoryGridView(data.data);
                    } else {
                      return Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      );
                    }
                  },
                ),
              ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

Comment: Please explain more about the pages that have problems, or you can use [sentry package](https://pub.dev/packages/sentry) to record an error

Comment: What do you see on the screen?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe you are using Expanded widget try to remove this

Comment: I removed Expanded widget but the problem is still there...

Comment: can you show some code snippet to check whats wrong on this

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this problem comes from Expanded/Flex widgets or setting Position in incorrect place

Please run your code and check if the loges show a message like "Incorrect Parent Widget" or "Unbounded widget" .. etc

I guess this is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I used it in some cases and worked:

```html
class MySmartFlex extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget child;
  MySmartFlex({Key? key, required this.child}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (kDebugMode) {
      return Flexible(
        child: child,
      );
    }

    return Container(
      child: child,
    );
  }
}
```